# javascript [array].splice not working ("Uncaught TypeError: collisions.splice is not a function")

Tags: javascript, arrays, svg

I am trying to remove specific items from an array in javascript, but cannot seem to get the [array].splice function to work. 
This code is to be used to check if an SVG object has collided with another (for a game). There are always expected to be 3 objects that the player intersects with, so I wish to remove these from the list. 
My code so far is:

```
svg=document.getElementById("canvas");

function checkcollision(){
    var r0=document.getElementById("rhb1").getBoundingClientRect(), r1=svg.createSVGRect(); r1.x=r0.left; r1.y=r0.top; r1.width=r0.width; r1.height=r0.height;
    var collisions=svg.getIntersectionList(r1,null), len=collisions.length;
    console.log(collisions);
    for(i=len-1;i>=0;i--){
        if(collisions[i].id=="renclosure"||collisions[i].id=="cplayer"||collisions[i].id=="rhb1"){
            collisions.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
    console.log(collisions);
    if(collisions.length>0){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

An example of what the console displays for the collisions array is

```
[<rect id=​"renclosure" x=​"0" y=​"0" width=​"15360" height=​"8640" class=​"st0">​</rect>​, <circle id=​"cplayer" cx=​"960" cy=​"540" r=​"50" class=​"st1">​</circle>​, <rect id=​"rhb1" x=​"0" y=​"0" width=​"100" height=​"100" class=​"st2" transform=​"translate(910, 490)​ rotate(0 050 050)​">​</rect>​]
```

(copied directly). 
However, Google Chrome throws up an error "Uncaught TypeError: collisions.splice is not a function" every time and I do not understand why (or how to fix it).

Comment: your collisions is not an array. Do this check `typeof collisions.construcotr == 'array'` and see what it gives

Comment: `getIntersectionList()` returns a Node List which is not an array. Do like `[...collisions].splice()` to have it working.

Comment: @Redu what kind of conversion is `[.. item]` can you give some link/docs, need to see this in detail! o.0

Comment: That's the spread operator of ES6. It's actually shortcut of using `Array.prototype.slice.apply(collision)` https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `collisions` is not of type `Array`

Try to use

`Array.prototype.splice.call(collisions, i, 1)`.

What about `splice.call()` see here [**Function.prototype.call**](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Comment: I'm now having a problem of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'length' of object '#<NodeList>'" in the console - I can manage to get it to run when typed through the console but when run from the script it seems to fail.

Comment: Try to use `slice` instead of `splice` and assign new object to another

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/SVGSVGElement, result of `getIntersectionList` is not an array but `NodeList`.

However, you can convert `NodeList` to an `Array` with following call:
`var div_array = Array.prototype.slice.call(div_list); // converts NodeList to Array`

More on that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList